How to stop org-latex-preview from turning the whole buffer or file to an image instead of the equation where the cursor is?
I stopped using emacs for a while, then upgraded to the latest emacs and I am having trouble with org-latex-preview. I am not sure what I used to use to preview images but that function turns the whole document to an image rather than the equation the cursor is on.
I can turn all of the equations into images without turning the whole document to an image in Latex mode.
[EDIT SOLVED: I had stopped using emacs for a while and I thought that I could use org-latex-preview in a latex .tex document. It seems the issue was that org-latex-preview was considering that the fragment that needed to be turned to an image was the entire text between \begin{document} and \end{document}. In an org mode document it seems like one does not use \begin{document} and \end{document} and in that case org-latex-preview only previews the equation where the cursor is]

Do C-h f org-latex-preview to see what fragment(s) are affected when you invoke it at various points and with various prefix arguments. When I invoke it with C-c C-x C-l and my cursor is on that fragment, only that fragment gets a preview. When I invoke it with C-c C-x C-l and my cursor is not on any fragment, then all fragments in that section get a preview.

@NickD thank you. I might have different keybindings because I am using doom emacs but I guess C-h f  is using helpful-callable with you as well. That function shows the source code, so I guess you are suggesting I try to understand the source code to see  why that is happening. I might try that but as I Imagine something is wrong somewhere and I am a beginner in emacs I considered seeing if anyone else had ever had that issue or would know why that happens.

@NickD When you say that all fragments in that section get a preview, do you see an image per fragment or do you see as I do one big image for the buffer

One image per fragment.

No: C-h f on standard Emacs calls describe-function which prints out the doc string of the function. That's what I was suggesting you should read.

Maybe you should add to your question a short version of your file with a couple of LaTeX fragments in it and describe what you do: it would help if you could start with emacs -Q so as to avoid your init file and Doom initialization as well, just to make sure that things are working at least at that level.

@NickD Sorry I stopped using emacs for a while and it seems like the issue was that I forgot that I needed to use org-latex-preview with .org files and not .tex files that have \begin{document} and \end{document} as org-latex-preview seems to consider that the latex fragment is everything between the outer most latex code which was \begin{document} and \end{document} in the document. I explained some of that in the question in an edit.

Yup - that's a correct diagnosis. You can use Auctex's latex-preview on LaTeX files. You can only use org-latex-preview on Org mode files.
